# Calculating user churn with Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, metrics

I'm trying to implement queries that calculate user retention and churn with PostgreSQL 9.5.2 following [this tutorial](https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/use-self-joins-to-calculate-your-retention-churn-and-reactivation-metrics.html)

I have a table of events defined as :

```
CREATE TABLE public.messages
(
  id character(100) NOT NULL,
  "userId" character(100),
  "createdAt" timestamp without time zone,
  CONSTRAINT messages_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
 WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

Calculating retained users is working just fine but I'm running into issues with counting "userId" that are nulls when running this query :

```
with monthly_activity as (
  select distinct 
    date_trunc('month', "createdAt") as month, 
    "userId"
  from messages
)
select 
  this_month.month, 
  count(distinct this_month."userId")
from monthly_activity last_month
left join monthly_activity this_month
  on this_month."userId" = last_month."userId"
  and this_month.month = last_month.month + interval '1 month'
where this_month."userId" is null
group by 1
```

Tables are being joined correctly but counting the null values seem to return no results.

Any hints on how I can get it to work?

Thanks!

Comment: `where this_month."userId" is null` You are explicitely selecting the NULL values from the LEFT JOIN. What else would you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `COUNT` function ignores nulls.   Your where clause is set to specifically ensure that `this_month."userId"` is always null.

Change your query to `count(distinct last_month."userId")` instead.

COUNT doc: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html